# Is there for every variety X an abelian variety A such that their 1st l-adic cohomologies are isomorphic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, motives, langlands-conjectures

This question is somewhat inspired by Kevin Buzzard's answer to [What is the interpretation of complex multiplication in terms of Langlands?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74776/what-is-the-interpretation-of-complex-multiplication-in-terms-of-langlands) and somewhat from my own curiosity about such topics.

Let $X$ be a variety over $\mathbb{Q}$. This variety induces a pure motive of weight $1$ (it induces pure motives of other weights, but I will focus on the one with weight $1$). I understand that weight $1$ motives come (conjecturally, of course) from weight $2$ newforms.

Okay, now let's trace it back. Let's start with a weight $2$ newform. Then, as James D. Taylor alluded to (and from what I know from http://staff.science.uva.nl/~bmoonen/MTGps.pdf), the corresponding newform must be the pure motive of weight 1 that is induced by an abelian variety (this is special to the weight $2$ newforms).

If so, then it seems that this proves that any pure motive of weight 1 is equal to the pure motive of weight 1 of a motive coming from some abelian variety.

Put back in words that are not conjectural:
Is it true that for every variety $X$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ there is an abelian variety over $\mathbb{Q}$, $A$, such that $H^1_{et}(X,\mathbb{Q}_l) \cong H^1 _{et} (A,\mathbb{Q}_l)$ as $Gal(\mathbb{Q})$-representations?

Or perhaps is the following weaker statement true (if I somehow managed to get something wrong in the above): For every variety $X$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, $L(X,s)$ (coming from the action on the pure motive of weight 1 -- which is well defined even without motives, since one can create it using $l$-adic cohomology) = $\prod_i L(A_i,s)$ where the $A_i$'s are (finitely many) abelian varieties over $\mathbb{Q}$ and the $L$'s are coming from their pure motives of weight $1$.

I would very much like to know, if the above is wrong, where exactly the fallacy was. But if everything above is right, then is this known without assuming crazy conjectures like the standard conjectures or forms of Langlands?

Comment: Doesn't the Albanese work?

Comment: Is that really all that is? I'm puzzled now... This is extremely basic compared with the fancy words I used, but why are their H^1's the same?

Comment: If you allow me to work with complex smooth projective varieties, then
here is the point: 
$$Alb(X)= H^0(X,\Omega_X)^*/H_1(X,\mathbb{Z})$$
up to torsion (which you'll throw away anyway), its first (co)homology  is the same as for $X$. Now use Artin to get the $\ell$-adic statement.

Comment: It seems to be implicit in the question and in the preceding comments that $X$ is smooth and projective (e.g. otherwise its $H^1$ need not be pure of weight $1$).  If you consider non-smooth or non-projective varieties, then you will have to consider not just abelian varieties, but $1$-motives.

Comment: By the way, pure weight $1$ motives over $\mathbb Q$ *of dimension $2$, and with Hodge numbers $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$* come from weight $2$ newforms; higher rank pure weight $1$ motives (even those with Hodge number just of the form $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, such as those coming about as $H^1$ of a smooth projective variety) will be attached to automorphic forms on other groups.



Comment: Emerton, that's a piece of the puzzle I haven't figured out yet. You're saying that pure weight 1 motives of dimension $>2$ don't come from an algebraic cuspidal automorphic representations of $GL_n(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$? Isn't the whole point that these representations correspond exactly to motives?
What is the context for looking at automorphic representations of other groups?

Comment: Or maybe what you meant by "other groups" is $GL_n(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$ as opposed to $GL_2(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$. (at first I thought you meant other reductive group schemes applied to the adeles)


Comment: In fact, you can find the autom representation on several groups at the same time. The group $GL_n(A_Q)$ always works, but I guess you can also find the autom representation on the symplectic group.


Comment: @ Donu: I don't quite follow your argument going from Betti cohom to l-adic cohom, as there's no Galois action on Betti. I suppose by "Artin" you mean Artin's comparison theorem in etale cohomology. 

Comment: Shenghao: you're right that my comment was cryptic and  incomplete
(and yes, by Artin, I mean the comparison theorem). Let me flesh it out a bit below.

Comment: Dear Makhalan, For concreteness, let's consider an abelian surface, whose $H^1$ is $4$-dim'l, and for which $h^{1,0} = h^{0,1} = 2$.  Then there should be an automorphic form for $GL_4$ giving rise to the $\ell$-adic reps. on its $H^1$.  But if we polarize the abelian surface than $H^1$ will be equipped with a symplectic pairing, and so (since the root system $C_2$ is self-dual) one would also expect an automorphic form on $GSp_4$ giving rise to the $H^1$.  (The form on $GL_4$ will be related to the form on $GSp_4$ via functoriality, applied to the standard embedding $GSp_4 \subset GL_4$.)

Comment: The existence of these automorphic forms is not proven yet (they fall outside the scope of existing modularity, or even potential modularity, theorems because $h^{1,0} = 2 > 1$, and present technology for $n > 2$ is restricted to (at best) the cases for which the variouss $h^{p,q}$s equal $0$ or $1$).   But there are people working on their existence currently, and they take $GSp_4$ as a starting point, not $GL_4$, because this group gives a Shimura variety, whereas
$GL_4$ doesn't, and without a Shimura variety at hand it's hard to make any contact between the automorphic and motiviv/Galois ..

Comment: ... worlds at all.  Regards, Matthew

Comment: @Arno Kret: the Galois representation is taking values in a symplectic group, so actually the automorphic representations would be for the dual group (in the sense of reductive groups) of a symplectic group, rather than the symplectic group itself (and actually one might even need an extra $GL(1)$ in order to have enough space to twist everything so things come out nicely).

Comment: @ Kevin Buzzard, yes you are right. Thank you !

Answer (score 8):

Let me slightly expand my comment from yesterday.  Unfortunately, because of
various time constraints, this will still be quite sketchy. Note that I'm only addressing the
titular question. I have nothing to say about the automorphic aspects, since it is too
far from what I know.

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{Q}$. For simplicity assume
that $X$ has rational point. I think there are various algebraic constructions of
the Albanese in the 1950's literature, but I have to confess I've never gone through
the details. So instead *define* $A=Alb(X) =Pic^0(Pic^0(X))$. After fiddling with the
Poincare sheaf and the given rational point, you should get a Abel-Jacobi morphism
$\alpha:X\to A$. I claim that this induces an isomorphism 
$$H^1(\overline{X}_{et},\mathbb{Q}_\ell)\cong H^1(\overline{A}_{et},\mathbb{Q}_\ell)$$
(where $\overline{X}= X\otimes \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$)
necessarily compatible with the Galois action. To see this, base change up to $\mathbb{C}$,
then by the comparison theorem, it suffices to get an isomorphism on the first singular (aka Betti) cohomology with $\mathbb{Q}$ coefficients. But the analytic construction of $Alb(X)$ gives this immediately because
$$Alb(X)= H^0(X_{an},\Omega_X^1)^*/H_1(X_{an},\mathbb{Z})$$
So the rational first homologies coincide, now dualize.

Comment: For the direct construction of the Albanese variety see Serre: Groupes algébriques et corps de classes. If I remember correctly he reproduces a proof by Lang but as always it is an eminently readable exposition.

Comment: By Barberi-Viale, Rosenschon and Saito, http://www.jstor.org/pss/3597296, a similar result holds for any complex algebraic variety. Of course, one needs to consider a 1-motive instead of an Abelian variety.

Comment: So without the assumption on the existence of rational points, we only know that these two Galois reps become isomorphic when restricted to some open subgroup, right?

Comment: From "inskspot's" answer, it appears that this is true on the nose
without restriction to an open subgroup.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to the OP's question in his para. 5 is ``yes'', I think. Even if $X/\mathbb Q$ has no $\mathbb Q$-point there is still an Albanese torsor $T$ (Lang, Abelian Varieties, p. 45, para. 3), universal with respect to morphisms from $X$ to abelian torsors, and then $H^1(X)$ is isomorphic to $H^1(T)$. Define $A=Aut_T^0$, so that $T$ is a torsor under $A$. The isomorphism $A\times T\to T\times T: (a,t)\mapsto (a(t),t)$ gives $H^1(A)\times H^1(T)\cong H^1(T)\times H^1(T)$. Then divide both sides by the copy of $H^1(T)$ coming from the second projection to get $H^1(A)\cong H^1(T)$, so $A$ is the abelian variety you want: $H^1(X)$ is isomorphic to $H^1(A)$.

Comment: Could you say precisely which reference "Lang" refers to?

Comment: Sorry, Lang's Abelian Varieties. I've edited my answer accordingly.